# Send message from website to Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to "communicate" my website (IIS) with my Google Chrome extension. I need to send a message from my website to the extension and then, the extension must return another message to the website to confirm receipt. Is it possible?

It's what I have tried:

*myWebsite.js*

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage(EXTENSION_ID, 'test', function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

*myExtension.js*

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request == EXTENSION_ID) {
             if(sender == "test") {
                   sendResponse('worked!');
             }
        }
    } 
);
```

It's not working. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should fill "externally_connectable" in manifest.json
2. you should listen to this message with chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal
3. request variable contains "test" string
4. sender variable is an object with "url" field, which is URL of the web-page

More information can be found [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage)